# Matching not equal to

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to make a regular expression that will return true when it comes across something like this:

```
MyField1 = 10293856
```

or

```
MyField1 = 72946392
```

The string of digits will always be a string of 8 digits. However, I want the following case to return false. This is the only case I need to worry about, a string of eight nines.

```
MyField1 = 99999999
```

How do I construct a regular expression that will do this for me?

I want the expression to check if

```
MyField1 = xxxxxxxx
```

Where the x's are all digits. But the only thing it cannot be is all 9's.

Comment: You want it to return false only when you see the string `MyField1 = 99999999`?

Comment: leading zeroes -- good or bad?

Comment: What exactly is wrong with `99999999`? Is it that exact string? 8 repeating digits? Or any number of repeating digits? You need to provide the actual pattern you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah, the only case I need to worry about is when the string of digits is 99999999. It can be any other string of digits, as long as it has a length of 8

Comment: Why do you need to use a regular expression exactly? Why don't you just make a regular expression that returns true when there are 8 9's a great deal easier. Although the 8 characters between 0 and 9999998 is trivial also.  A regular expression IS NOT THE CORRECT TOOL for this job, its overkill, its like using a double barrel gernade launcher when you hunt rabbits.

Comment: I'm not sure why folks are downvoting this question. This is a perfectly valid question (although it could be more clearly stated) for which a regex solution is perfectly applicable. I'm giving your question a +1 to help compensate.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the `MyField1 = 10293856` string appears on one line of a file, here is a regex that should do the trick

```cs
if (Regex.IsMatch(text, 
    @"# Match 'var = 8digitval', where 8digitval is not all nines.
    ^                # Anchor to start of line.
    MyField1[ ]=[ ]  # Fixed literal var name & equals sign.
    (?!9{8}$)        # Assert value is not eight nines.
    [0-9]{8}         # Value is eight digits.
    $                # Anchor to end of line.
    ", 
    RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)) {
    // Successful match
} else {
    // Match attempt failed
}
```

The above regex will match all lines having the hard-coded variable named: `MyField1`. If you wish to match other variable names, (with a variable amount of whitespace surrounding the equals sign), this one may be more what you are looking for:

```cs
if (Regex.IsMatch(text, 
    @"# Match 'var = 8digitval', where 8digitval is not all nines.
    ^           # Anchor to start of line.
    \w+\s*=\s*  # Variable var name & equals sign.
    (?!9{8}$)   # Assert value is not eight nines.
    [0-9]{8}    # Value is eight digits.
    $           # Anchor to end of line.
    ", 
    RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)) {
    // Successful match
} else {
    // Match attempt failed
}
```

Comment: I had no idea you could do that: (?!9{8}$)        # Assert value is not eight nines.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a regex.

```
public static bool Validate(string strNum)
{
    bool ret = false;
    Int32 num = 0;
    if (Int32.TryParse(strNum, out num))
    {
        if (num != 99999999)
        {
            ret = true;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

You could also have the function return the parsed int as well as an `out` argument or in the return.

Comment: This is a pretty robust solution. However, it will reject 0099999999 which may be what the op wanted, but didn't specifically request.

Comment: I think the OP is trying to extract the 8-digit number from the text

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're parsing this out of a text file?  Your question is somewhat unclear as to the exact nature of the input, or what you're doing.  The following uses a Regex to find the name and value on a line of text, and then evaluates the constraint.

```
static void Main()
{
    const string Test = @"MyField1 = 10293856
```

MyField1 = 72946392
MyField1 = 99999999
MyField1 = 12356642";

```
    Regex exp = new Regex(@"^(?<Name>\w+)\s*=\s*(?<Value>\d{8})\s*$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
    foreach(Match match in exp.Matches(Test))
    {
        string name = match.Groups["Name"].Value;
        string value = match.Groups["Value"].Value;

        if (value != "99999999")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", name, value);
        }
    }
}
```

This is really as close as you're likely to get with an expression, since you can not find the 8 digit string and then test the value to see if it's all 9's.

You can also do this with a Linq expression:

```
    Regex exp = new Regex(@"^(?<Name>\w+)\s*=\s*(?<Value>\d{8})\s*$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
    foreach(Match match in exp.Matches(Test).OfType<Match>().Where(m => m.Groups["Value"].Value != "99999999"))
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^([0-8]\d{8})|(\d[0-8]\d{7})|(\d{2}[0-8]\d{6})|(\d{3}[0-8]\d{5})|(\d{4}[0-8]\d{4})|(\d{5}[0-8]\d{3})|(\d{6}[0-8]\d{2})|(\d{7}[0-8]\d{1})|(\d{8}[0-8])$
```